# Mac Big Sur repeatedly tries to open "Open Office" for no obvious reason. I suspect malware

Tags: mac, malware, openoffice, macos-bigsur

**Something** is periodically (every hour or so) trying to open "OpenOffice" while I'm working in other apps.  Because OpenOffice was previously downloaded onto my machine, I get a warning about opening a potentially dangerous piece of software for the first time. So I cancel.  An hour or so later, the dialog will appear and ask again.

I have no idea what process is trying to launch OpenOffice, or why.

Does anyone recognize this behavior?  Is it likely from malware?
How can I determine what is attempting to open the app?

Comment: It sounds like you did more the just download it. Sounds like an installation was at least started. If you still have the download look for an uninstaller, it might even be in the installer itself. If you don't have the installer I would go to where you downloaded it again and see if there is an uninstaller.

Comment: When this happens, could you try opening Terminal and running `ps aux | grep OpenOffice`? That should at least show if any arguments were passed to the program.

Comment: @SteveChambers - I want to know what process is attempting to launch OpenOffice, not simply to uninstall the app.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks.  This looks like a good suggestion, although I'm comfortable in Terminal I couldn't get it to give results. I executed the command and there were two issues: 1) it didn't find any (other) process attempting to launch OpenOffice.  2) It doesn't appear to show arguments passed to any of the processes.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm tempted to write a trivial Mac app to simply display the launch parameters.  Then if I make that app the default for all the file types opened by OpenOffice, I should be able to see what file it is attempting to open.  That may shed some light.  Are there any "healthy" periodic tasks that would open a word-processing file?  If I've confused my file associations, could Console or some other process be trying to open a legit file?